# How to get a document from a Cloud Firestore collection based on index?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

For developing an Android app in Kotlin, I am trying to find a way to retrieve a document from a Firestore collection based on a certain index and I am not sure how to go about it. For example, if my collection has 50 documents, what would be the best way to retrieve the 10th document so that I can populate text views on my app based on the field values of that document?

Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: The documents will be stored with a hash id in cloud firestore and not with index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add documents to Firestore using the [CollectionReference#add()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/CollectionReference#add(java.lang.Object)) method, you'll see a random document ID that is assigned automatically for each document. If you check the Firebase Console or you try to query a collection programmatically, you will not find any order for the containing documents. This means that there is no index involved. So it's not correct to say, hey Firestore, give me the 10th document, because when you query a collection of 50 documents, the 10th document might be the one you are interested in, but if you add/delete documents, the 10th document won't be the same.

You might think, ok, I can provide my own document IDs, starting from 0 - 49, and when I query the collection I can order them by their document IDs. But, this is not an option, since the document IDs are always strings, and when you order strings, the order is [lexicographical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order).

The best solution I can think of, if you need to get a particular document from a collection, is to add a specific field in that document, so it can be identified very easily. For instance, you can add a particular name or ID for each document, and then you can perform a query that looks like this:

```
rootRef.collection("users").whereEqualTo("name", "Bhavey")
```

In this way, you can simply identify each one of the documents in your collection.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question. I understand now. I will instead add a field and retrieve the fields in the document retrieved using a successListener.

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this, will require some setup.

let's say you have a collection of documents and you want to manage them and find the 10th document, Firestore generates unique hash id's that are based on the timestamp making them have an inherent order based on the time they were generated.

All you need to do is manage a dedicated document in the parent of this collection that contains an array of all document id's in the subcollection.
reading this document and it's array would get you an ordered list of documents without incurring the additional reads of the documents as other methods, even listing the ID's requires 1 read each.

on the successful operation of it being added, you can use a `Cloud Function` `onCreate` trigger to push the document id to the master array and the same with `onDelete`. But if cloud Functions are not available or you want to brute force it from the client, you can do the following:

```java
db.collection("users")
        .document("uid")
        .collection("posts")
        .add(city)
        .addOnSuccessListener { documentReference ->
                db.collection("users")
                .document("uid")
                .update("index", FieldValue.arrayUnion(documentReference.id))
                .addOnSuccessListener { Log.d(TAG, "Index Added!") }
                .addOnFailureListener { e -> Log.w(TAG, "Index Error", e) }
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { e -> Log.w(TAG, "Error source document", e) }
```

Cloud Functions sources:

- [trigger_a_function_when_a_new_document_is_created](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#trigger_a_function_when_a_new_document_is_created)
- [trigger_a_function_when_a_document_is_deleted](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#trigger_a_function_when_a_document_is_deleted)

**note: to scale this past 1mb firestore document limits - you will need multiple index documents with a counter and to manage this with Cloud Functions. The end result should double your writes without crippling your reads*